# React: Can component constructor have more than 1 parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Just curious can a component constructor have more than 1 parameter?

From:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
```

Into:

```
constructor(props, parent) {
    super(props)
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

So the parent can assign `this.parent` inside the child component.

For example this is the parent component want to initialize the child:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.helpers = new Child(<i_am_not_sure_here>, this);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the parent inside the props?

Comment: I thought the `props` should not be changed, but yes that works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:

- Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
- Binding event handler methods to an instance.

Check out the official docs for more information:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

I tested and I got an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)
```

In addition, docs didn't mention anything about extra properties.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor